# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Expected an expression, got 'end of print statement'

Tags: html, python, flask

soy nuevo en programación y estaba siguiendo un video tutorial sobre como crear una pagina web con Flask (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icbGQxVJB7I). Pero me trabe en el minuto 26 cuando intenta abrir una html con una variable en ella. En el video el puede realizarlo, pero a mi me aparece este error jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Expected an expression, got 'end of print statement' al cargar la pagina.

Este es mi código en HTML =>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hola</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola, {{ name }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi codigo en Python =>

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/<string:nombre>/')
def saludo(nombre):
    return render_template("saludo.html", name= nombre)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

PD: Ya intenten modificando la sintaxis de la variable de estas formas:

```
{% name %}
{ name }
% name %
```

Comment: Hola @Eduardo, a mi tu codigo me funciona. Versiones de flask,jinja... exactamente que URL no te funciona?

Comment: El html que muestras es `saludo.html`? Y qué hay en `index.html`? No será éste el que te está dando error?